# Norm of an operator induced by $L^2$-kernel is bounded by $L^2$- norm of the kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I am currently studying Hilbert Schmidt operators on my own using the book "Functional Analysis" (Vol 1) by Reed and Simon.

There it is stated that a function $K \in L^2(M \times M, d\mu \otimes d\mu)$ induces an operator
$$
A_Kf(x) = \int_M K(x,y) f(y) \,d\mu(y)
$$
and the operator norm is dominated by the $L^2$-norm of $K$, that is $\|A\| \le \|K\|$.

I am trying to verify this norm estimate but got stuck. Here is what I did:

We have
\begin{align}
\|A_K\|^2 &= \sup_{\|f\| = 1} \int\left|\int K(x,y) f(y) \,d\mu(y)\right|^2\,d\mu(x)\\
&= \sup_{\|f\| = 1} \int\int K(x,y) f(y)\,d\mu(y) \overline{\int K(x,z)f(z)\,d\mu(z)}   \,d\mu(x)\\
& \le \sup_{\|f\| = 1} \int\int |K(x,y) f(y)|\,d\mu(y)  \int |K(x,z)f(z)|\,d\mu(z)   \,d\mu(x) \\
& \le \sup_{\|f\| = 1} \int(\|K_x\|\|f\|)(\|K_x\|\|f\|)  \,d\mu(x)\qquad \text{(Cauchy Schwarz)}\\
&= \int \|K_x\|^2 \,d\mu(x)
\end{align}
where $\|K_x\|$ refers to the norm of the function $K(x, \cdot) \in L^2(M,d\mu)$. But how can I finish this argument, and is it correct to start with? I don't have a lot of experience with product measures, this must be a pretty elementary fact that I am missing most likely about the relationship of $d\mu \otimes d\mu$ to its component measures .. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $$\left\lvert \int K(x,y)f(y)\,d\mu(y)\right\rvert^2.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in fact done, since 
$$\lVert K_x\rVert^2=\int K(x,y)^2\mathrm d\mu(y),$$
and we get what we want integrating with respect to $x$.

Notice that we can use Cauchy-Schwarz directly in the inner integral of the RHS of the first line.